# Error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to create the Kibana loader: Error creating Kibana client

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I'm having a problem when I try to run the command sudo metricbeat -e -setup
it return  Error importing Kibana dashboards: fail to create the Kibana loader: Error creating Kibana client

but if I run sudo metricbeat test config

Config OK

or

sudo metricbeat test modules

nginx...
  stubstatus...OK
    result:
    {
     "@timestamp": "2018-10-05T12:30:19.077Z",
     "metricset": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1:8085",
      "module": "nginx",
      "name": "stubstatus",
      "rtt": 438
     },
     "nginx": {
      "stubstatus": {
       "accepts": 2871,
       "active": 2,
       "current": 3559,
       "dropped": 0,
       "handled": 2871,
       "hostname": "127.0.0.1:8085",
       "reading": 0,
       "requests": 3559,
       "waiting": 1,
       "writing": 1
      }
     }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Kibana is up and running?
Kibana IP and Port are configured correctly in metricbeat?

Metricbeat starting from V6.x are importing their dashboards into Kibana, thus resulting in errors like this if the Kibana endpoint isn't reachable.